# Find answered % rate of any Stack Exchange community

Tags: support, site-stats

There is an option to find answered percentage for each tag on Stack Overflow, but I want to know if there is any way I can check the answered rate of [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: If you are using a query on the Data Explorer, you can change which site is being queried at the bottom of the query input box where it says "Switch Sites"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [Sites list on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users):

> [image]